# futex-based 4-byte single-writer/multiple-readers lock

Tags: locking, contention, futex

Looking for a minimal, [futex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex)-based implementation of a single-writer/multiple-readers lock requiring no space overhead beyond a single 4-byte futex state variable.

Some background: I have an application which will embed a lock within each of tens to hundreds of millions of small objects.  Because of the very fine grained nature of the locking and the structure of the application I anticipate minimal contention.  Further, writers will be rare and contending writers rarer still.  For all of these reasons, in this particular setting, a solution prone (in theory) to the "thundering heard" phenomenon is quite acceptable.

Comment: You cannot build a working, POSIX-compliant rwlock using nothing but a single futex. Please clearly define the desired behavior of your rwlock. For example: Must it support recursive read locking? Must a blocked writer prevent further read locks, or is starving writers not a concern? It would be enough to provide a documented version of the API you expect.

Comment: Jeremy, If you reread the description of my problem I never indicated a need for POSIX compliance.  I expect minimal contention but require support for both shared and exclusive locking.

Comment: (Continuing previous comment) Having received no pointers to potential solutions I ended rolling my own.  My implementation is indeed futex-based.  It provides 1, 2 and 4 byte variants, supports up to 63 readers in a 1 byte lock and 16383 readers in a 2 byte lock.  On an x86 non-contended transitions typically require a single atomic cmpxchg.  My company was just bought by IBM.  I am checking if I can release the code under GPL.

Comment: Beware of Smoku's code, it has a bug. When a write lock is released it will only wake 1 reader instead of all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You will find my implementation at https://gist.github.com/smokku/653c469d695d60be4fe8170630ba8205

The idea is that there can be only one thread taking the lock for write (futex value `0`), lock can be open (futex value `1`) or there can be many reading threads (futex values greater than `1`). So values below `1` (there is only one) block both readers and writers on futex, and values above `1` block only writers. Unlocking thread wakes one of waiting threads, but you need to be careful not to consume a readers only wake by a writer thread.

```c
#define cpu_relax() __builtin_ia32_pause()
#define cmpxchg(P, O, N) __sync_val_compare_and_swap((P), (O), (N))

static unsigned _lock = 1; // read-write lock futex
const static unsigned _lock_open = 1;
const static unsigned _lock_wlocked = 0;

static void _unlock()
{
    unsigned current, wanted;
    do {
        current = _lock;
        if (current == _lock_open) return;
        if (current == _lock_wlocked) {
            wanted = _lock_open;
        } else {
            wanted = current - 1;
        }
    } while (cmpxchg(&_lock, current, wanted) != current);
    syscall(SYS_futex, &_lock, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1, NULL, NULL, 0);
}

static void _rlock()
{
    unsigned current;
    while ((current = _lock) == _lock_wlocked || cmpxchg(&_lock, current, current + 1) != current) {
        while (syscall(SYS_futex, &_lock, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, current, NULL, NULL, 0) != 0) {
            cpu_relax();
            if (_lock >= _lock_open) break;
        }
        // will be able to acquire rlock no matter what unlock woke us
    }
}

static void _wlock()
{
    unsigned current;
    while ((current = cmpxchg(&_lock, _lock_open, _lock_wlocked)) != _lock_open) {
        while (syscall(SYS_futex, &_lock, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, current, NULL, NULL, 0) != 0) {
            cpu_relax();
            if (_lock == _lock_open) break;
        }
        if (_lock != _lock_open) {
            // in rlock - won't be able to acquire lock - wake someone else
            syscall(SYS_futex, &_lock, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1, NULL, NULL, 0);
        }
    }
}
```